Rate limiting middleware in ASP.NET Core MVC
I am trying to add the rate limiting middleware to my ASP.NET Core MVC web application.
I add a global and partitioned FixedWindowLimiter via
services.AddRateLimiter(...) 

and activate it using
app.UseRateLimiter()

I have a controller, which must not be rate limited and therefore I added the attribute [DisableRateLimiting] on that one. But, this attribute is ignored by the middleware and I have no idea, why this is happening.
In the documentation is written, that app.UseRouting() must be called before app.UseRateLimiter(). I do not use app.UseRouting(),
but app.UseMvc(...), which is the last one in the pipeline.
When I put app.UseRateLimiter() after app.UseMvc(...), the global rate limiter is not working. Otherwise, the attribute on the controller is not working.

Could you please share your current program.cs? Besides, have you tried to use it like this app.UseRouting();app.UseRateLimiter(); app.MapControllerRoute(     name: "default",     pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

Thanks for your reply!
My Program.cs is completely unspectacular, because I am using a startup class. It is just WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<..>().Build();
I am using areas, is that one possible with app.MapControllerRoute(...)?

Switch from app.UseMvc() to app.UseRouting() and app.UseEndpoints(). This aligns with the middleware pipeline required for the rate limiter and ensures the pipeline order is correct:
app.UseRouting();
app.UseRateLimiter();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });

This should fix both the global rate limiter and the [DisableRateLimiting] attribute.

Thanks for your reply!
I am using areas, is that possible with app.UseEndpoints()?

what do you mean with areas?
